# How to Slide Left to Right an Element by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide, jquery-effects

Trying to Slide `h3` title to right direction by jquery to this [slider](http://slycore-demo.blogspot.com). This slider has fade effect by default, I'm trying give slideRight effect to `h3` title of slider.

*HTML:*

```
<div id="headslide">
    <ul>
        <li class="post-content">
            <div class="slidshow-thumbnail">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-h4-nQvZ5-VE/VQ3HLtSS3ZI/AAAAAAAABIc/iaOda5zoUMw/s350-h260-c/girl_with_winter_hat-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg" height="260" width="350"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <span class="content-margin">
                <p>Cicero famously orated against his p...</p>
                /* Title */
                <h3><a href="#">Download Premium Blogger Templates</a></h3>
                <span class="info">Info</span>
            </span>
        </li>

        <li class="post-content">
            <div class="slidshow-thumbnail">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-YfkF1u_VB40/VWr5dYf00gI/AAAAAAAABW8/wv2e-Lu4etw/s390-h340-c-h340-c/11071467_807062866056131_872486685669967339_n.jpg" height="260" width="350"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <span class="content-margin">
                <p>SEO friendly Flat style Custom Fonts.</p>
                /* Title */
                <h3><a href="#">Modern with a pixel-perfect eye</a></h3>
                <span class="info">Info</span>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried this
 `$(".content-margin").delay(400).show("h3", { direction: "right" }, 1200);`

Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bacec898/3/) >>. I'm trying to do this by jquery.

*any suggestion?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is about as close as the .cycle is going to allow.
Hopefully This is what you were going for.
Change ".content-margin" if you want something else to be animated.

```
  $('#headslide ul').cycle({
    timeout: 4000,
    pager: '#headslide .pager',
    before: resetMe,
    after: slideMe
});
function resetMe() {
      $(".content-margin").fadeIn();
    $(".content-margin").css( "left", "-=50" )
}

function slideMe() {
  $(".content-margin").animate({
    left: "+=50",
  }, 2000, function() {
  $(".content-margin").fadeOut();
     });
}
```

I can't get the forked fiddle link to run but when I copy and paste the code into your fiddle it works great.
.Cycle doesnt really allow for animate, so you can use the "before" and "after" to call functions that do the animation you are looking for. This just treats .cycle like a loop.

Comment: HI, it's not working/not slide, please check your fiddle.

Comment: Sorry. For some reason the forked fiddles will not run correctly. Just copy and paste my javascript into your fiddle and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Just change this in your CSS:

```
#headslide h3 {
-webkit-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
-moz-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
-o-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
animation-name:bounceInLeft;
```

to this:

```
#headslide h3 {
-webkit-animation-name:bounceInRight;
-moz-animation-name:bounceInRight;
-o-animation-name:bounceInRight;
animation-name:bounceInRight;
```

Comment: Thanks, i know that, i'm trying do that by jquery.

Comment: Hi dear, by default it's working without any change/help on Chrome/opera, but problem it's not working/slide in Firefox. please check it on firefox. so i trying to do this by juuery, but still not working on firefox, why?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this jquery code

```
$.fn.cycle.defaults = { 
    activePagerClass: 'activeSlide', // class name used for the active pager element 
    after:         null,  // transition callback (scope set to element that was shown):  function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) 
    allowPagerClickBubble: false, // allows or prevents click event on pager anchors from bubbling 
    animIn:        null,  // properties that define how the slide animates in 
    animOut:       null,  // properties that define how the slide animates out 
    autostop:      0,     // true to end slideshow after X transitions (where X == slide count) 
    autostopCount: 0,     // number of transitions (optionally used with autostop to define X) 
    backwards:     false, // true to start slideshow at last slide and move backwards through the stack 
    before:        function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag){
       $(".content-margin").css("margin-left",$(".content-margin").width());
        $(nextSlideElement).children(".content-margin").animate({"margin-left":"0px"});
    },  // transition callback (scope set to element to be shown):     function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) 
    cleartype:     !$.support.opacity,  // true if clearType corrections should be applied (for IE) 
    cleartypeNoBg: false, // set to true to disable extra cleartype fixing (leave false to force background color setting on slides) 
    containerResize: 1,   // resize container to fit largest slide 
    continuous:    0,     // true to start next transition immediately after current one completes 
    cssAfter:      null,  // properties that defined the state of the slide after transitioning out 
    cssBefore:     null,  // properties that define the initial state of the slide before transitioning in 
    delay:         0,     // additional delay (in ms) for first transition (hint: can be negative) 
    easeIn:        null,  // easing for "in" transition 
    easeOut:       null,  // easing for "out" transition 
    easing:        null,  // easing method for both in and out transitions 
    end:           null,  // callback invoked when the slideshow terminates (use with autostop or nowrap options): function(options) 
    fastOnEvent:   0,     // force fast transitions when triggered manually (via pager or prev/next); value == time in ms 
    fit:           0,     // force slides to fit container 
    fx:            'fade',// name of transition effect (or comma separated names, ex: 'fade,scrollUp,shuffle') 
    fxFn:          null,  // function used to control the transition: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, afterCalback, forwardFlag) 
    height:        'auto',// container height (if the 'fit' option is true, the slides will be set to this height as well) 
    manualTrump:   true,  // causes manual transition to stop an active transition instead of being ignored 
    metaAttr:      'cycle',// data- attribute that holds the option data for the slideshow 
    next:          null,  // element, jQuery object, or jQuery selector string for the element to use as event trigger for next slide 
    nowrap:        0,     // true to prevent slideshow from wrapping 
    onPagerEvent:  null,  // callback fn for pager events: function(zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) 
    onPrevNextEvent: null,// callback fn for prev/next events: function(isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) 
    pager:         null,  // element, jQuery object, or jQuery selector string for the element to use as pager container 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: null, // callback fn for building anchor links:  function(index, DOMelement) 
    pagerEvent:    'click.cycle', // name of event which drives the pager navigation 
    pause:         0,     // true to enable "pause on hover" 
    pauseOnPagerHover: 0, // true to pause when hovering over pager link 
    prev:          null,  // element, jQuery object, or jQuery selector string for the element to use as event trigger for previous slide 
    prevNextEvent:'click.cycle',// event which drives the manual transition to the previous or next slide 
    random:        0,     // true for random, false for sequence (not applicable to shuffle fx) 
    randomizeEffects: 1,  // valid when multiple effects are used; true to make the effect sequence random 
    requeueOnImageNotLoaded: true, // requeue the slideshow if any image slides are not yet loaded 
    requeueTimeout: 250,  // ms delay for requeue 
    rev:           0,     // causes animations to transition in reverse (for effects that support it such as scrollHorz/scrollVert/shuffle) 
    shuffle:       null,  // coords for shuffle animation, ex: { top:15, left: 200 } 
    slideExpr:     null,  // expression for selecting slides (if something other than all children is required) 
    slideResize:   1,     // force slide width/height to fixed size before every transition 
    speed:         1000,  // speed of the transition (any valid fx speed value) 
    speedIn:       null,  // speed of the 'in' transition 
    speedOut:      null,  // speed of the 'out' transition 
    startingSlide: 0,     // zero-based index of the first slide to be displayed 
    sync:          1,     // true if in/out transitions should occur simultaneously 
    timeout:       4000,  // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance) 
    timeoutFn:     null,  // callback for determining per-slide timeout value:  function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) 
    updateActivePagerLink: null, // callback fn invoked to update the active pager link (adds/removes activePagerClass style) 
    width:         null   // container width (if the 'fit' option is true, the slides will be set to this width as well) 
};
$('#headslide ul').cycle({
    fx:      'scrollRight',
    next:   '#headslide ul',
    timeout: 4000,
    pager: '#headslide .pager' });
```

Comment: Thanks, but trying to slide only `h3` Title element, not whole slider.

Comment: should the image be same for all the h3 content.

Comment: How to slide only `h3` Title element?

Comment: Hi @Aabira i have updated code for h3 slide effect. The options used is to get the callback method "before" which triggers on slide transition.

Comment: Nice, see your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bacec898/11/  it's not work properly, not slide every time and it should slide only `h3` element, not to other elements.